# How would one make multiple exception classes inherit from one parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So far I have this...

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from Mailchimp::Exception::DataException,
    Mailchimp::Exception::APIKeyError,
    Mailchimp::Exception::NotFound,
    Mailchimp::Exception::Duplicate,
    Mailchimp::Exception::MissingField,
    Mailchimp::Exception::BadRequest,
    Mailchimp::Exception::UnknownAttribute,
    Mailchimp::Exception::MissingId,
    with: :error

  def error(e)

    puts 'Message: ' + e.message
    puts 'Type: ' + e.type
    puts 'Title: ' + e.title

    e.errors.each do |error|
      puts 'Field: ' + error['field']
      puts 'Message: ' + error['message']
    end if e.errors

    # Respond to the HTTP POST request by passing the errors
    return render_with(500, e.message, e.errors)

  end

  private

  def render_with(status_code, message, errors='none')

    if errors == 'none'
      status = 'success'
      success = true
    else
      status = 'error'
      success = false
    end

    render json: {
      :status => status,
      :success => success,
      :message => message,
      :errors => errors,
      :params => params.as_json
    },
    status: status_code

  end

end
```

In an attempt to make it DRY, I have done this...

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

  mailchimpExceptions = [
    'DataException',
    'APIKeyError',
    'NotFound',
    'Duplicate',
    'MissingField',
    'BadRequest',
    'UnknownAttribute',
    'MissingId'
  ]

  exceptions = Array.new

  mailchimpExceptions.each do |exception|
    exceptions << "Mailchimp::Exception::#{exception}"
  end

  rescue_from *exceptions, with: :error

  def error(e)

    puts 'Message: ' + e.message
    puts 'Type: ' + e.type
    puts 'Title: ' + e.title

    e.errors.each do |error|
      puts 'Field: ' + error['field']
      puts 'Message: ' + error['message']
    end if e.errors

    # Respond to the HTTP POST request by passing the errors
    return render_with(500, e.message, e.errors)

  end

  private

  def render_with(status_code, message, errors='none')

    if errors == 'none'
      status = 'success'
      success = true
    else
      status = 'error'
      success = false
    end

    render json: {
      :status => status,
      :success => success,
      :message => message,
      :errors => errors,
      :params => params.as_json
    },
    status: status_code

  end

end
```

I am wondering if all the exceptions could by under one class, so that only one class is called like `rescue_from MailchimpExceptions, with: :error`. [This answer by mgolubitsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835861/1298155) suggests it is possible, but I have no idea how to go about it.

I am using gem 'mailchimp_api_v3'.

Comment: what gem are you using?

Comment: @thaleshcv 'mailchimp_api_v3'

Comment: Yeah, it's really an oversight on mailchimp's part. I see no possible reason _not_ to have a common error class for your gem. Probably, your best bet is to do what @mudasobwa is suggesting.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ar okay. So am I right in saying that the gem author could just use one class, rather than have multiple classes as declared on [this page](https://github.com/dominicsayers/mailchimp_api_v3/blob/develop/lib/mailchimp_api_v3/exception.rb)?

Comment: Maybe there _was_ a reason for this, I have no idea. Note that _most_ of them inherit from DataException. So you can rescue that one and the few rogues.

Comment: Yeah, good spot! And also 'RuntimeError' would be one other I imagine?

Comment: Now, `RuntimeError` is one of the system classes and is too generic. Don't rescue _that_ one.

Comment: Ar okay, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/dominicsayers/mailchimp_api_v3#exception-handling

It says:

> All exceptions will be subclasses of Mailchimp::Exception

try `rescue_from Mailchimp::Exception, with: :error`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work - It doesn't rescue the exception. I seem to remember trying that before, as I also read that line in the README.md

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about mailchimp itself, but I can generally suggest how to make it DRY properly:

```
EXCEPTIONS = %w|
  DataException
  APIKeyError
  NotFound
  Duplicate
  MissingField
  BadRequest
  UnknownAttribute
  MissingId|.map { |e| Mailchimp::Exception.const_get(e) }

rescue_from *EXCEPTIONS, with: :error
```

Or, to `rescue_from` **all exceptions**, defined in `Mailchimp::Exception` at once:

```
EXCEPTIONS = Mailchimp::Exception.constants.map do |e|
  Mailchimp::Exception.const_get(e)
end.select { |e| e.is_a?(Class) && e < Exception }
```

Comment: Real tidy! Like it! Though the latter didn't work, I think because of an error on this [gem page](https://github.com/dominicsayers/mailchimp_api_v3/blob/develop/lib/mailchimp_api_v3/exception.rb) `ArgumentError ({"RestClient::ResourceNotFound"=>Mailchimp::Exception::NotFound, "RestClient::Unauthorized"=>Mailchimp::Exception::APIKeyError} must be an Exception class or a String referencing an Exception class):`

Comment: Simply filter out everything that is not an exception. I have the answer updated.

Comment: That doesn't pick up anything - In other words, it produced an empty array

Comment: Oh, indeed. `e` is a class there, not instance, please see an update.

Comment: Now `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Class into Hash):`. Maybe the Class name needs to be grabbed as a string?

Comment: I blindly try to guess how mailchimp constants look like, while you have it on hand. OK, not I am sure it will work as expected.

Comment: I think what you are after is instances, not constants. [This the class in which you are looking in](https://github.com/dominicsayers/mailchimp_api_v3/blob/develop/lib/mailchimp_api_v3/exception.rb)