# Inserting a value into an array under some condition

Tags: ruby

How can I add value to an array inline under some condition?

This example:

```
["aaa", ("bbb" if false)]
# => ["aaa", nil]
```

adds `nil`, but, I do not want to add anything:

```
["aaa"]
```

Comment: `["aaa", ( "bbb" if false), ('ccc' if true)].compact` ?

Comment: @kiddorails it’ll damage arrays allowing `nil`s in general.

Comment: `["aaa"].tap { |arr| arr << "bbb" if false }`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin agreed :)

Answer (score 4):

You either do:

```
["aaa", ("bbb" if false)].compact
```

or:

```
["aaa", *("bbb" if false)]
```

But be careful with certain classes when you use the second option, as it may mess up objects of certain classes. For example, a hash would be converted into an array:

```
["aaa", *({b: :b} if true)]
# => ["aaa", [:b, :b]]
```

Comment: *("bbb" if false) what exactly mean *, Could you send link to description this notation?

Comment: That is called the splat. You can read [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781639/passing-multiple-error-classes-to-rubys-rescue-clause-in-a-dry-fashion/5782805#5782805) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would even post this as an answer since that’s a most succinct and clean way to accomplish this task.

```
["aaa"].tap { |arr| arr << "bbb" if false }
```

---

In more generic and easy to follow way:

```
input = [42]
to_add = {true: :true, false: :false}

to_add.each do |needed, value|
  input.tap { |arr| arr << value if needed }
end
#⇒ [42, :true]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concat an empty array when the condition is false, which essentially does nothing:

```
["aaa"] + (1==1 ? ["foo"] : [])
 => ["aaa", "foo"]
["aaa"] + (1==2 ? ["foo"] : [])
 => ["aaa"]
```